# Camera picture from storage to imageview?

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I have a code, where you can take a picture, and then save it like 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg. The problem is that I have no idea how to display the taken image in my second activity.

```
   Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Here, the counter will be incremented each time, and the
                // picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg
                // and likewise.
                count++;
                String file = dir+count+".jpg";
                File newfile = new File(file);
                try {
                    newfile.createNewFile();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                }

                Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to pass my image as parcable, the quality is pretty bad, that's what I don't want. Anybody can help me with this, or show a good guide? The most important is that I don't want to display it in my first activity, I want to display it in my second activity, calling the path of the 1.jpg. Thanks!

Comment: Pass the `Uri` (`outputFileUri`) as an extra to the second activity. Have the second activity pull out that extra, then use [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) like Picasso to put the image in your `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

The way is to write the picture taken to a file and get the path to said file and passing the path to the next activity and intializing a bitmap using said path to file and setting the image view...ill post a code soon

mean while look into [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/) while i post a snippet
EDIT: SNIPPET
this code sets up camera to take a picture and save to a file.

```
private void onCameraSelected() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_CAMERA);
    }

    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
    }

    private File getOutputMediaFile() {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

on the onActivityResult detect resultcode/request code for camera and consume it like so

```
private void loadImageFromCamera(Intent data) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger images
//            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);
            setLoadedImage(bitmap);// set bitmap to imageview here.
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.logError("File not found :" + fileUri.getPath());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Basically youre playing with the variable `String filePath = fileUri.getPath();` // just declare Uri fileUri in activity level or something.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the camera intent a location to save the image.  You then have to retrieve the image from the phones storage in order to display it in an image view.

set a member variable to keep track of the image:

```
private Uri mImageUir;
```

Then to request a camera intent:

```
File photo = null;
try {
    // place where to store camera taken picture
    photo = createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg");
    photo.delete();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mImageUir = Uri.fromFile(photo);
intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUir);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
```

...

```
private File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception
{
    File tempDir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    tempDir=new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/.temp/");
    if(!tempDir.exists())
    {
        tempDir.mkdir();
    }
    return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
}
```

Then in your `OnActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //firstly find correct orientation of photo
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    Integer photoOrientation = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(mImageUir.getPath());
        photoOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap photo;
    ContentResolver resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    try {
        //get the image file
        photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, mImageUir);

        //You should scale it down here if you dont need in full size

        //rotate to correct orientation
        if(photoOrientation != null) {
            photo = rotateBitmap(photo, photoOrientation);
        }

        mYourImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        //delete temporary image file (if you need to)
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my method to rotate the image:

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            return bitmap;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            break;
        default:
            return bitmap;
    }
    try {
        Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return bmRotated;
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```